# Is it OK to set start and end text nodes for Range object in Java?

Tags: java, xml, dom, cursor

I need to determine whether the cursor is within XML range.
I've set start and end text nodes for Range.
I suppose that compareBoundaryPoints method does not work properly for this case. Surely, I can be wrong.
In Java I use `com.arbortext.epic.ADocument`, `org.w3c.dom.ranges.Range` imports.
`holeRange_` is a `org.w3c.dom.ranges.Range` object.

```
holeRange_ = ((DocumentRange) txtProcessor_.GetDocument()).createRange();
holeRange_.setStart(startNode, 0); //text node
holeRange_.setEndAfter(endNode); //text node
```

Here is the body of click event handler:

```
Range caretRange = ((ADocument) txtProcessor_.GetDocument()).getInsertionPoint();
    if (caretRange != null) {
     DebugMode.println(caretRange.getStartContainer().getNodeValue());
     DebugMode.println("END_TO_START = " +
      textNodeRange_.compareBoundaryPoints(Range.END_TO_START, caretRange));
     DebugMode.println("START_TO_END = " + 
      holeRange_.compareBoundaryPoints(Range.START_TO_END, caretRange));
    }
```

The output gives END_TO_START = -1 and START_TO_END = -1 when the cursor is inside the range.
According to [Check if specified element is inside selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9324654/check-if-specified-element-is-inside-selection) the values should be: END_TO_START = -1 and START_TO_END = 1.
Is the problem linked with it:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=148126

Comment: ...Any code to show, by the way? What's a range object?

Comment: @JimmyGustafsson - Well, to be fair llya had like 4 or 5 unanswered Q's

Comment: @Adel - Indeed that's true. Didn't realize that. I think he still might benefit from reading the links provided tho.  @ Ilya - This question is hard to answer in it's current state. Please try to post relevant code of what you've tried, and why it's not working and more people will be able to help you with your problem

Comment: This question is completely without context to the problem. compareBoundaryPoints, is that part of a frame work or a method you created? What framework are you using to traverse your dom? What range are you talking about, Dom's Children? OR entire Document? Maybe you have so many unanswered question is because you are not asking correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tired bro!
I've made a tiny port of a triple of methods (`compareBoundaryPoints`,`isAncestorOf`,`indexOf`) for Range object from xerces c++ XML library to Java. I've forgotten about Xerces2 Java.
Well, I've made a set of experiments which showed that the xerces `compareBoundaryPoints` implementation is more adequate.

Comment: Note: I have to use 1.4 Java for that XML Editor. I suppose that compareBoundaryPoints bug has been eliminated in newer versions.

Comment: Note: `compareBoundaryPoints` works badly if you deal with non-normalized xml. It's because the logic uses `getNextSibling()` method which returns null in the case of Text nodes.